# How can I make all pages urls of my joomla 3 web site have the .html extension?

Tags: joomla-3.4, url, sef, seo, global-configuration

How can I make URLs showing the .html extension in all my pages?

For example, http://localhost/site/contacts.html

I use joomla 3.

Comment: The OP want his urls have the .html extension at the end. No need to close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to show it:
For adding the document extension type in your URLs, you need to go in:
  **-> Global Configuration**
  **-> Site**
  **-> enable the "Add Suffix to URL" setting, at the SEO Settings section.**

Note that this may be overridden by rules in your **.htaccess** file, or **3rd party SEF extensions**, so in case you have it enabled in Global Configuration but it doesn't show, you need to review those.

Most people don't like the extension in their URLs, why you want to have it?

Comment: Visitors will think that my site is made of only html.

Comment: And html is the most secure extension

Comment: @ITEngineer, Glad if I helped you... if that answers your question, consider to accept is as answer. But regarding your comments: Let's say that visitors pay attention to your .html extension and go a step farther to make thoughts such "Oh this is a html website" - what's your benefit of this? And what is the relation of the extension your urls will have and security?

Comment: @FFrewin maybe trying for security through obscurity? IT Engineer, if that is what you are aiming for, you will also need to remove Joomla generator tags and check that your server is not putting information in the headers it sends,etc etc.

Comment: Sure, that is ...

Comment: Security through obscurity is not security. People will always know your site is Joomla. Period.

Comment: @PhilTaylor, how will they know?

Comment: @ITEngineer, the thing is that what you are trying to hide is for audience that you don't have to fear - that audience might hardly know what is html... and even will never pay attention to the .html extension on your urls or anything else. Most of them think when viewing a site, as this is "Internet" or it is their computer. But you can't hide your Joomla site from those who knows, bots etc.

Comment: @FFrewin, I have understood! Clear.